# Поместить цикл в цикл Custom Field Suite Плагин

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть карточка тренера на сайте. В каждой карточке 3 фото тренера выполнены слайдером.  Карточка выводится с помощью цикла в плагине произвольных полей Custom Field Suite. Когда помещаю в цикл карточки тренера цикл с картинками слайдера, то картинки не выводятся. Первый цикл отрабатывает и выводит данные имя и описание тренера. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
   <?php
    $fields = CFS()->get( '2_trainers_loop' );
    if( ! empty($fields) ):
        foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
            ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="treiner-slide-card row">

                <div class="col-md-3 trainer-slider">
                <?php
                $fields2 = CFS()->get( '_slider_photo_trainer' );
                if( ! empty($fields2) ):
                foreach ( $fields2 as $field2 ) {
                ?>
                    <div class="slide-trainer">
                        <img src="<? echo $field2['_slider_photo_trainer_img'];?>" alt="1">
                    </div>

                    <?php
                };
                endif;?>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="slide-trainer-name"> <? echo $field['2_trainer_name'];?></div>
                        <div class="slide-trainer-description"><? echo $field['2_trainer_description'];?></div>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-name="<? echo $field['2_trainer_name'];?>" data-target="#exampleModal2" class="buttons price-card-button"> Выбрать</a>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

            <?php
        };
    endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
$fields = CFS()->get('2_trainers_loop');
if (!empty($fields)):
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        ?>
        <div class="row trainer-card-wrapper">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="treiner-slide-card row">

                    <div class="col-md-4 trainer-slider">

                        <?php
                            $images = $field['_slider_photo_trainer'];
                        foreach ($images as $img) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="slide-trainer">
                            <img src="<? echo $img['_slider_photo_trainer_img']; ?>" alt="1">
                        </div>
                        <?php }; ?>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="slide-trainer-name"> <? echo $field['2_trainer_name']; ?></div>
                        <div class="slide-trainer-description"><? echo $field['2_trainer_description']; ?></div>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-name="<? echo $field['2_trainer_name']; ?>"
                           data-target="#exampleModal2" class="buttons price-card-button trainer-choose"> Выбрать</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
    };
endif; ?>
```